# right usage of slick filter

Tags: scala, slick, playframework-2.3

I'm using slick to access database. I want to query like this:

```
case class Coupon(couponId: Long, shopId: String)

class Coupons(tag: Tag) extends Table[Coupon](tag, "coupons"){

  def couponId = column[Long]("coupon_id")

  def shopId = column[String]("shop_id")

  override def * = (couponId, shopId) <> (Coupon.tupled, Coupon.unapply)
}

object Coupons extends TableQuery(new Coupons(_)){

  def findCouponBy(couponId: Long, shopId: Option[String]) = {

    val s = DB.createSession()
    try {
       val q = for {
           coupon <- this.filter(c => c.couponId === couponId && 
                shopId.map(s => c.shopId === s).getOrElse(true)
        } yield coupon
      s.database.run(q.result)
    } finally s.close
  }
}
```

I thought this might work. However, the compiler tells me that 
Error:(126, -1) Play 2 Compiler: 
 type mismatch;
  found   : Any
  required: slick.lifted.Rep[?]

Problem lies on here:
    shopId.map(s => c.shopId === s).getOrElse(true)

I'm wondering how I can make this work.

I'm using slick 3.0.0-RC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `slick.lifted.LiteralColumn(true)`

Scala's type infer limitation

Comment: And I was wondering that, I want to take this out as a method:  `shopId.map(s => c.shopId === s).getOrElse(true)`    as `def checkCondition[T](column: Rep[T], parameter:T) = { column === parameter }`       Is there a way to make it through?

Comment: parameter: Rep[T] or maybe checkCondition[T:TypedType] or checkcondition[T:BaseTypedType]

Comment: there's a little hook on the left of the answer

Answer (score 1):

As it is mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55365966/5091346) answer, you can use the following API since [Slick 3.3.0](http://slick.lightbend.com/news/2019/01/30/slick-3.3.0-released.html):

```
def findCouponBy(couponId: Long, shopId: Option[String]) = {
  val query = 
    this
      .filter(_.couponId === couponId)
      .filterOpt(shopId){ case (table, sid) =>
        table.filter(_.shopId === sid)
      }

  db run query.result
}
```