# Dynamic query with optional where clauses using Slick 3

Tags: scala, playframework, slick

I'm trying to implement a method to return filtered results, based on a set of parameters which may or may not be set. It doesn't seem like chaining multiple filters is possible conditionally, i.e. starting off with one filter...

```
val slickFlights = TableQuery[Flights]
val query = slickFlights.filter(_.departureLocation === params("departureLocation").toString)
```

Conditionally adding another filter to the query (if it exists in the Map of params) doesn't seem to work...

```
if (params.contains("arrivalLocation")) {
      query.filter(_.arrivalLocation === params("arrivalLocation").toString)
}
```

Can this sort of conditional filtering be done using Slick through other means?

I've come across the MaybeFilter: https://gist.github.com/cvogt/9193220, which seems to be a decent approach for handling exactly this. However it doesn't seem to work with Slick 3.x

Following Hüseyin's suggestions below, I have also tried the following:

```
def search(departureLocation: Option[String], arrivalLocation: Option[String]) = {
    val query = slickFlights.filter(flight =>
       departureLocation.map {
          param => param === flight.departureLocation
       })
```

Where `slickFlights` is a TableQuery object `val slickFlights = TableQuery[Flights]`. However this produces the following compilation error:

```
value === is not a member of String
```

Intellij also complains about the === being an unknown symbol. Doesn't work with == either.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For the benefit of anyone else trying to get optional filters working in Slick, have a look at the answer here: [right usage of slick filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30090872/right-usage-of-slick-filter/30091582#30091582). I finally managed to get it working with the following:

```
def search(departureLocation: Option[String], arrivalLocation: Option[String]) = {
  val query = for {
    flight <- slickFlights.filter(f =>
       departureLocation.map(d => 
         f.departureLocation === d).getOrElse(slick.lifted.LiteralColumn(true)) && 
       arrivalLocation.map(a => 
         f.arrivalLocation === a).getOrElse(slick.lifted.LiteralColumn(true))
    )
  } yield flight
```

The key bit being the `.getOrElse(slick.lifted.LiteralColumn(true))` on the end of the map, which causes Slick to render SQL as follows if for example only the departureLocation is set...

```
select * from `flight` 
where (`departureLocation` = 'JFK') and true
```

whereas without it the SQL looked like...

```
select * from `flight` 
where (`departureLocation` = 'JFK') and (`arrivalLocation` = '')
```

which obviously meant that it came back with no rows.

Comment: Thanks for this, still helpful to this day

Answer (score 14):

A simpler approach without for comprehension:

```
import slick.lifted.LiteralColumn

val depLocOpt = Option[Long]
val slickFlights = TableQuery[Flights]
val query = slickFlights.filter { sf => 
  if (depLocOpt.isDefined) sf.departureLocation === depLocOpt.get
  else                     LiteralColumn(true)
}
```

**UPDATE:** you can shorten it more with `fold`:

```
val depLocOpt = Option[Long]
val slickFlights = TableQuery[Flights]
val query = slickFlights.filter { sf => 
  depLocOpt.fold(true.bind)(sf.departureLocation === _)
}
```

Answer (score 14):

## January 2019

### No more need to invent your own wheels!

At last [Slick 3.3.0](http://slick.lightbend.com/news/2019/01/30/slick-3.3.0-released.html) includes the following helpers:

- [`filterOpt`](http://slick.lightbend.com/doc/3.3.0/api/index.html#slick.lifted.Query@filterOpt[V,T%3C:slick.lifted.Rep[_]](optValue:Option[V])(f:(E,V)=%3ET)(implicitevidence$1:slick.lifted.CanBeQueryCondition[T]):slick.lifted.Query[E,U,C])
- [`filterIf`](http://slick.lightbend.com/doc/3.3.0/api/index.html#slick.lifted.Query@filterIf(p:Boolean)(f:E=%3Eslick.lifted.Rep[Boolean]):slick.lifted.Query[E,U,C])

So, for example:

```
case class User(id: Long, name: String, age: Int)
case class UserFilter(name: Option[String], age: Option[Int])

val users = TableQuery[UsersTable]

def findUsers(filter: UserFilter): Future[Seq[User]] = db run {
  users
    .filterOpt(filter.name){ case (table, name) =>
      table.name === name
    }
    .filterOpt(filter.age){ case (table, age) =>
      table.age === age
    }
    .result
}
```

Comment: So simple now! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Ross Anthony's (excellent) answer can be further generalized by using foldLeft:

```
slickFlights.filter { f =>
    val pred1 = departureLocation.map(f.departureLocation === _)
    val pred2 = arrivalLocation.map(f.arrivalLocation === _)
    val preds = pred1 ++ pred2  //Iterable
    val combinedPred = preds.foldLeft(slick.lifted.LiteralColumn(true))(_ && _)
    combinedPred
}
```

This way when introduced with another optional constraint, it can simply be mapped (like `pred1` and `pred2`) and added to the `preds` Iterable, the foldLeft will take care of the rest.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Slick 3.3.x. My solution is:

```
def search(departureLocation: Option[String], arrivalLocation: Option[String]) =
  slickFlights
    .filterOpt(departureLocation)(_.departureLocation === _)
    .filterOpt(arrivalLocation)(_.arrivalLocation === _)
```

Answer (score 0):

I just came up with a new soluion:

```
implicit class QueryExtender[E, U, C[_]](base: Query[E, U, C]) {
  def filterOption[T: BaseTypedType](option: Option[T], param: E => Rep[T]) = {
    option.fold {
      base
    } { t => base.filter(x => param(x) === valueToConstColumn(t)) }
  }
}
```

If you have a query (`slickFlights`) an option value and a selector, you can use it with `slickFights.filterOption(departureLocation, _.departureLocation)`.