# How to filter on a Option[Boolean] column in slick

Tags: scala, slick, slick-3.0

I have the following column in my db, thats a Boolean, but also accepts NULL, so true, false, and NULL are all valid:

```
def rtb = column[Option[Boolean]]("rtb")
```

and have the following optional input from the client that I'd like to filter on:

```
rtbFromClient: Option[Boolean] = ...
```

I have the following (based on this answer on how to do queries in slick:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/40888918/5300930):

```
val query = userTable.
      filter(row => 
          if (rtbFromClient.isDefined) 
              row.rtb.get === rtbFromClient.get 
          else 
              LiteralColumn(true)
      )
```

but am getting this error when the code runs:

```
Caught exception while computing default value for Rep[Option[_]].getOrElse -- This cannot be done lazily when the value is needed on the database side
```

I thought it may be because row.rtb.get was throwing exception on call to get because the value in the db was null, so tried changing it to row.rtb.getOrElse(null) and row.rtb.getOrElse(None) but neither of these worked either)

Also tried the following:

```
if (rtbFromClient.isDefined) {
    val query = query.filter(_.rtb.isDefined).filter(_.rtb.get === rtbFromClient.get)
}
```

But this also throws the same error at runtime:

```
Caught exception while computing default value for Rep[Option[_]].getOrElse -- This cannot be done lazily when the value is needed on the database side
```

To summarise:

- I have an Option[Boolean] column in my db that can contain true, false or NULL (the actual mysql type is a tinyint(1), which is mapped to a slick Option[Boolean])
- I have an optional filter provided by the user, rtbFromClient that I'd like to filter on if present. If present, this will be either true or false
- I have other optional filters (not shown here) that have similar behavior so I'd like to be able to combine them easily

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var query = userTable.drop(page.skip).take(page.top)

if (rtbFromClient.isDefined) {
    query = query.filter(row => row.rtb.isDefined && row.rtb === rtbFromClient)
}

// More if blocks with optional filters here
...

dbProvider.db.run(query.result)
```

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue. My solution is (tested with Slick 3.3.x):

```
val query = usersTable.filterOpt(rtbFromClient)(_.rtb === _)
```

Situation 1 (when rtbFromClient is empty) corresponds the following SQL:

```
select * from users;
```

Situation 2 (rtbFromClient is defined):

```
select * from users where rtb = ?;
```

Answer (score 2):

Fist check if the column is null and then go ahead with another comparison. Ensure that `rtbFromClient` is not an option.

```
val query = userTable.filter(row => !row.rtb.isEmpty &&
                                    row.rtb === rtbFromClient)
```

The first condition ensures that nulls are filtered and the second condition checks the value in case the column value is not null.

In case you have optional value, then below code helps.

```
def query(value: Option[Boolean]) = value match {
   case Some(userGivenRtbFromClient) =>
    userTable.filter(row => !row.rtbFromClient.isNull &&
         row.rtbFromClient === userGivenRtbFromClient)
   case None => userTable.filter(row => row.rtbFromClient.isNull)
}
```

The Much cleaner version is here.

```
rtbFromClient: Option[Boolean]
```

`rtbFromClient` User given optional value to compare with slick column.

```
userTable.filter(row => rtbFromClient.map(value => row.rtb === Some(value): Option[Boolean]).getOrElse(row.rtb.isEmpty))
```

Comment: This doesn't work in the scenario where rtbFromClient is None, in that case no filtering should be performed - see the else LiteralColumn(true) in the original question

Comment: @Rory Simple change can help, when none is present. edited the ans

Comment: What if I have multiple optional filters though? I can't chain them this way - filter(...).filter(...)

Comment: @Rory `query` returns a query so, after that you can do chaining with `map`, `filter` etc

Comment: @Rory use this `userTable.filter(row => optional.map(_ === row.rtbFromClient).getOrElse(row.rtbFromClient.isNull))`. this is much better

Comment: What is 'optional'?

Comment: Also, there is no isNull function on row. rtbFromClient - it is a Rep[Option[Boolean]]

Comment: @Rory replace `isNull` with  `isEmpty` . added details in answer.

Comment: @Rory clarified in answer

Comment: This doesn't compile, says 'cannot find symbol ===': userTable.filter(row => rtbFromClient.map(_ === row.rtb).getOrElse(row.rtb.isEmpty))

Comment: @Rory use this `userTable.filter(row => rtbFromClient.map(row.rtb === _).getOrElse(row.rtb.isEmpty))` ... Just shifted the `_` to right. Becoz `===` is defined on Rep

Comment: Doesn't compile: Type slick.lifted.Rep[_ >: Option[Boolean] with Boolean] cannot be a query condition (only Boolean, Rep[Boolean] and Rep[Option[Boolean]] are allowed
[error]     val query = advertiserTable.filter(row => rtb.map(row.rtb === _).getOrElse(row.rtb.isEmpty))

Comment: @Rory try this `userTable.filter(row => rtbFromClient.map(value => row.rtb === Some(value): Option[Boolean]).getOrElse(row.rtb.isEmpty))`

Comment: @Rory this will definitely work. `userTable.filter(row => rtbFromClient.map(value => row.rtb === Some(value): Option[Boolean]).getOrElse(row.rtb.isEmpty))`

Comment: This doesn't compile: type mismatch;
[error]  found   : Some[Boolean]
[error]  required: slick.lifted.Rep[?]

Comment: @Rory Please paste the compiler error in the comments section

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156550/discussion-between-pamu-and-rory).

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
val query = userTable.filter(row => rtbFromClient.map(x => Option(x) === row.rtb).getOrElse(row.rtb.isEmpty.?))
```

Comment: Can you explain that further such that others can learn from it?

Comment: it's a direct answer to the asked question. At least it works for me well (i had the same problem)

Comment: Well, as you posted this as an answer, I guess that's what it should be :) But please add some explanation to that code: what does it do? Keep in mind that people come here to learn from such answers, not just to copy&paste them

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue. After playing around I realised one can filter by the option directly, so if we have the column

```
def rtb = column[Option[Boolean]]("rtb")
```

and we're trying to filter by

```
rtbFromClient: Option[Boolean] = ...
```

then we can do:

```
val query: DBIO[Seq[TableElementType]] = 
  if (rtbFromClient.isDefined)
    userTable.filter(_.rtb === rtbFromClient).result
  else
    userTable.result
```